# Dynamic title like in the Notes app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, title

when the user enters text in a uitextview I would that the title of the navigation bar changed dynamically like it happens in the Notes app.

How can I achieve this?

I think a label is used, don't I?

Thanks

Fran

EDIT: I know how change the title of a navigation bar, but how do this in a such way that the textview is tied to the title, so while user enters the first line of text in the same moment the title changes (letter by letter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67624-set-navigation-bar-title-while-user-enters-text-like-notes-app.html#post277783)

Answer (score 2):

```
UINavigationItem *navItem;
navItem = [UINavigationItem alloc];
navItem.titleView = lblTitle;
[navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:false];
[navBar setDelegate:self];
```

Got this info from: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7015-set-title-uinavigationbar.html

Answer (score 2):

I know you can set the title of a navigation controller from within a child view controller simply via:

```
[self setTitle:@"Required title"];
```

or

```
[[self NavigationController] setTitle = @"Required title"];
```

However, these may not work interactively. (Not at a Mac OS X box otherwise I'd try it out.)